# ModuleNotFound while Dockering python app

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-import

I have a simple python app, which uses custom class I've created. The following folder structure is the following:

```
│ mains
|   ├── run_it.py
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── parsers
    │   ├── parser.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
```

In the run_it.py, the main program, I'm calling

```
from mains.parsers.parser import Parser
```

In local mode I've added to ~/.bashrc the line and it works good:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/.../THE_FOLDER_ABOVE_MAINS"
```

But when I try to dockerize the app, I get the following error:

```
File "/app/run_it.py", line 11, in <module>
from mains.parsers.parser import Parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mains'
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip3 install gunicorn
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=2"
CMD ["gunicorn","run_it:app"]
```

Any idea how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work properly outside of docker?

Comment: Yes, thohg I've added to ~/.bashrc file the following line: export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/username/THE_FOLDER_ABOVE_MAINS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see you set any module path in container, then for your case, the folder `app` which run the top script `run_it.py` was automatically added to module path.

As a result, you should use next:

```
from parsers.parser import Parser
```

And another way add next to your Dockerfile(suppose it's the same folder of mains) too:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
```

Then you can still use `from mains.parsers.parser import Parser`

Comment: When I change it at the PyCharm I get the following compilation error: `Unresolved reference 'parsers'`

Comment: @Flo They are empty (as they should be, no?)

Comment: You mean when run? How you run in pycharm?

Comment: Not when I rut, when I change the code - even without running it. I run in pycharm using just running run_it.py

Comment: But if you in CMD, could you run it with `run_it.py`? I mean out of IDE, you are in windows? Anyway directly run it bash or cmd, have a try.

Comment: I can run it from cmd (I use ubuntu). Though without the changes you said. I think your changes are correct but how can I make pycharm declare mains as a package? Now the docker is fine but pycharm is problematic

Comment: So, if do not use the above method, just use my second method `add PYTHONPATH to dockerfile`, is it work for you?

Comment: I don't know pycharm well, maybe any project cache, maybe need to use a new project? But if you do not want to change code on IDE, then just similar to on host, add PYTHONPATH to container is also a way. BTW, the `Dockerfile` is in the parent folder of `mains`?

Comment: 1) What PYTHONPATH changes should I add? 2) Dockerfile is in the mains folder.

Comment: Just similar as you do on host. Put `ENV PYTHONPATH=/app` in `Dockerfile`. You confirm the folder structure in container is `/app/mains/...`? THe `ENV` in dockerfile will reserve to running container.

Comment: Er, could you move `Dockerfile` to the parant folder of `mains`? You want to use the same code with `mains` in package name, but with your currents sturucture, the `mains` folder even not in container. I mean `mains` & `Dockerfile` had better to be in same folder.

Comment: Yeah, that solved all the problems. Thank you very much mate!

Answer (score -1):

Try this its working..

from parsers.parser import Parser

[image]